# searching an element in binary tree using in order traversal

Tags: c, search, data-structures, binary-tree

```
struct tnode
{
    int val;
    struct tnode *left;
    struct tnode *right;
};

int search(struct tnode *root, int val)
{
    int p = 0;
    int q = 0;
    if (!root) return 0;
    p = search(root->left, val);
    if (p == 1) return 1;
    if (root->val == val) return 1;
    q = search(root->right, val);
    if (q == 1) return 1;
}
```

I am not understanding how the above code is returning `0` when `val` is not found while searching the tree.

Comment: Replace two last lines with `return q;`

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. Without an MCVE, it's hard to say for sure what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah, that works but I want to know why the above code is working. Because, at a point of time there is no return value. when root becomes null it returns 0 to called function and is stored in either p or q but neither of them is returned again.

Comment: Why even have such a function?  Normally, a tree search function returns the node or a pointer to it. Just knowing it's there, you still have to search for it to do anything with it. What you have, is a useless exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is an unstructured function. There are four return statements and five possible return paths. One of the returns explicitly returns zero, the others explicitly return 1, therefore either you are calling `search` with NULL for `root` or the fifth implicit return path just happens to return zero.

Dial up the warning level on your compiler, it should have flagged the fact that not all execution paths return a value.

I suggest you rearrange your logic such that there is a single return statement at the end of the function.

Comment: Since this is obviously a homework assignment, I am not going to fix your code for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I should check the warning level in the compiler.It works by using few return statements but I was wondering why the above code was not throwing an error that 'it has reached end of the function with no return value'

Answer (score -1):

Here, I am using stack for the iterative inorder traversal of a tree.

```
int find_element(struct node *root,int val){

     if(!root) return 0;
     std::stack<node*> s;
     while(!s.empty() || root){
          if(root){
              s.push(root);
              root=root->left;
          }
          else
          {
              root=s.top();
              s.pop();
              if(root->val==val) return 1;
              root=root->right;
          }
     }
     return 0;
}
```